# Release file error (Docker installation on Linux VM)

Tags: linux, windows, docker, ubuntu, virtual-machine

I'm using the following command as part of my Docker installation (I follow the instructions here: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/)

```
sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"
```

I get the following error:

> The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release Release' does not have a Release file.

I have encountered this before when I was still trying the Docker installation through Windows Subsystem Linux (my machine is a Windows 10 Home) after problems with directly installing Docker for Windows Home. At that time I tried something with sources.list as recommended elsewhere, but this resulted in an error about a malformed entry in sources.list. I never managed to resolve it (sources.list didn't even seem to show fully in the terminal), so I ended up trying the current approach, which is Docker installation inside a Linux virtual machine with the following distribution:

> Linux version 5.3.0-26-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-013) (gcc version 9.2.1 20191008 (Ubuntu 9.2.1-9ubuntu2)) #28-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 18 05:37:46 UTC 2019 (Ubuntu 5.3.0-26.28-generic 5.3.13)

The VM was created with Oracle Virtualbox. I would really appreciate some advice on how to go about the Release file error. I'm completely new to Docker and Linux, and not very proficient with terminals in general.

Thanks for any support and patience.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. There is something you don't see and/or you did not explain correctly in your question. The `add-apt-repository` command you referenced is ok (just tested). Meanwhile your error message shows that `$(lsb_release -cs)` was not expanded correctly (it should be replace by your ubunu version name). You have to find out what is wrong when you type it in your terminal. Moreover, this is a question related to Docker installation under ubuntu, not to programming and it's therefore off-topic here (see [site help](/help)). Try https://superuser.com or https://askubuntu.com

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for responding despite the misplaced question here. I tried to be more precise in my repost on AskUbuntu. About ``` lsb_release -cs ```, this gives eoan, which is exactly my Ubuntu version name, no?

Comment: Make sure you are running the command in a bash shell.